# Github Actions - Elevated permission to start/stop iis server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using Github actions to deploy .net core web api site to IIS. I am using self-hosted runner to download and copy files to the web server. But being the files are in use, we have to stop IIS site and then start again. I am using network service to run the github actions.

I have to give administrator logon for the network service to make it work. But being we are giving full permissions to the tool which is a security flaw. Is there any other way to accomplish this without exposing the security flaw?

Comment: Give specific permissions to the network user (you don't need to give it admin to give it permissions to restart services) or create a user specifically for the runner and set its permissions according to your needs.

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer on serverfault.com.

Comment: You can edit a specific service's permissions and allow specific users to start/stop the service without granting any other permissions. https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/view-edit-service-permissions-windows/?utm_content=cmp-true
But a better solution would probably be to not restart IIS completely, but to control only the application pools instead.